# $\phi^4$-theory: Feynman diagrams loop integral calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, integration, regularization

I am studying quantum field theory by myself, could anyone help me with this integral? How can I get this result? Be more specific?

[image]

Comment: Been a while. I seem to recall there is a contour integral involved.

Comment: Introduce Feynman parameter, shift the momentum to a Gaussian, do the Gaussian ... I am a bit surprised this is not explained elsewhere in these notes.

Comment: I think you need to find the poles of the integrand, then apply Cauchy's integral theorem. Then argue why the part of the integral vanishes due to that the argument goes the zero for $\Lambda \rightarrow \infty$ (i.e. they state the assumption after they calculated the integral, but this is already needed to apply Jordan's lemma). So you need to find the residues of the integrand and then use Cauchy integral formula

Comment: Both of these methods will struggle with the fact that the upper limit is finite (and is not taken to infinity as is seen by the dependence on $\Lambda$ on the rhs)

Comment: This question is most definitely not off topic as there is a precise and relevant question being asked, so it should not be on hold. Those who voted thus should declare  the reasons why so that op can improve the question if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a quick and dirty way to get here. The logarithmic divergence is in $\Lambda$ so is coming from the $|q| \gg 1$ region of the integral. For fixed $p$ and $m^{2}$ and in the part of the region of integration $|q|$ large we can make the approximation $q^{2} - m^{2} \sim q^{2}$ and $(q - p)^{2} - m^{2} \sim q^{2}$. Now we have
$$d^{4}q = d\Omega_{3} \,dq \,q^{3}$$
where $d\Omega_{3}$ is the angular measure and $dq \,q^{3}$ the radial measure. For large $q$, then,
$$\int_{|q| \leq \Lambda} \frac{d^{4}}{(2\pi)^{4}} \frac{i}{q^{2} - m^{2}}\frac{i}{(q-p)^{2} - m^{2}} = \int \frac{d\Omega_{3}}{(2\pi)^{3}} \int_{0}^{\Lambda} \frac{dq}{2\pi} \, q^{3} \, \frac{i}{q^{2} - m^{2}}\frac{i}{(q-p)^{2} - m^{2}} \sim \int \frac{d\Omega_{3}}{(2\pi)^{3}} \int^{\Lambda} \frac{dq}{2\pi} \, q^{3} \, \frac{-1}{q^{4}}$$
where I'm taking the leading order divergent behaviour from the radial integral. Now the angular part gives $\textrm{Vol}(S^{3})$, the volume of the three-sphere, whilst the radial integral has leading behaviour
$$\int^{\Lambda} \frac{dq}{q} = \ln \frac{\Lambda}{p}$$ where the factor of $p$ comes either from dimensional analysis or from the asymptotic form of the integrand for $q \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So the parameter "a" in the formula in the book contains the information of the Vol(S3)?  I want to calculate some real processes containing 1-loop calculations and renormalizations which can be compared with experiments, could you give me a some references?

Comment: Yes, the volume integral and a load of other details are all put together into a. In general it would be hard to calculate a, at least for a chosen sensitivity. I will see if I can find some refs. By the way, thank you for accepting my answer (I hope you keep using this wonderful site). If you're really shpoy with it you could also press the up arrow to vote the answer up :-)

Comment: Thanks, what does "shpoy" mean?

Comment: Oh woops, sorry about that - I meant to say " if you're really happy with it"...